# Is it possible to configure Jira/X-Ray so that the X-Ray tests can be used as sub-tasks?

Tags: agile, jira

We are using JIRA for Agile programming using 'Stories'.

The stories have sub-tasks to complete the work and we would like to use X-Ray tests as sub-tasks, but the only issue type JIRA makes available for sub-tasks is 'Technical Task'.

How do we configure JIRA to have X-Ray test available as a Story sub-task?

Answer (score 1):

What Xray provides is the ability to create Sub Test Executions as sub-tasks of a Story, for example. More info here: https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY/Sub-Test+Execution

Since a Test is somehow like a test case template reusable, even for later version, maybe it makes more sense to have the "execution" related task as a sub-task instead.
With Sub Test Executions you can track them directly in the Agile boards, as something right below the related Story, as depicted here: https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY/Agile+Enhancements#AgileEnhancements-QuickviewofExecutionsforRequirementsfromAgileBoard

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that lets you define different types of sub-types: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.brokenbuild.subtask-types/server/overview

Personally I would not make it to complicated and use technical tasks. Maybe just add [X-Ray] to the start of the summary. Or add a label called X-ray. This so you can filter on them from the boards or other locations. Creating X-Ray tests is a technical task, not? :)